# SQL query: how to merge merge query with the most efficient way

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a number of tables and I want to isolate the data from each of them and calculate the total.

```
SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count from (
    SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count from table_1 GROUP BY country
    union all
    SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count from table_2 GROUP BY country
    union all
    ............
    union all
    SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count from table_n GROUP BY country)
A GROUP BY country;
```

The problem for this query is to fetch the result from table_1 ... table_n before the final calculation. this would make the size large and takes lots of memory.

Would there be a solution to improve it.

Something like

```
SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count from (
    SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count from table_1 GROUP BY country
    union all
    SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count from table_2 GROUP BY country) 
A GROUP BY country;

then 

SELECT country, SUM(count) (
A 
    union all (SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count from table_3 GROUP BY country)
) A GROUP BY country;

......

until table_n
?
```

Would someone please advice any better solution?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Your query does have a very subtle bug because you are using `union` instead of `union all`, but that doesn't seem to be your concern.

Comment: The `SUM` and the `GROUP BY` in the subqueries are not needed and will likely generate a little overhead

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the unions:

```
SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count
FROM (SELECT country, SUM(COUNT) AS count
      FROM table_1
      GROUP BY country
      UNION ALL
      SELECT COUNTRY, SUM(count) AS count
      FROM 
          (SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count
           FROM table_2
           GROUP BY country
           UNION ALL
           SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count
           FROM
               (SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count
                FROM table_3
                GROUP BY country
                UNION ALL
                SELECT country, SUM(count) AS count
                FROM table_4
                GROUP BY country)
           GROUP BY country)
      GROUP BY country)
GROUP BY country
```

Keep nesting them as many times as necessary for all your tables.

An alternative is save the intermediate unions into temporary tables.

Comment: No, sorry, this is not what I am talking about.

Comment: I was missing some `GROUP BY` clauses, I think it's now what you asked for.

Comment: Sorry mate, you have missed understanding what I am asking.
You can see, the query will be expanded according to the size of the tables which are needed. Say if there are 1000 table, the query will be extremely long

Comment: Sounds like you need a stored procedure that creates dynamic SQL to loop through all the table names, merging them into a temporary table.